# How to rotate the 'FallingSand' blocks with /setblock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering how to change the rotation of my dispenser in this command:

```
/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {Block:"minecraft:dispenser",Time:1}
```

It faces down when it is spawned; how can I change it to face east?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to rotate a block, you must specify the [Block Data](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dispenser#Block_data) which is essentially its rotation. In terms of the actual command you want created it would look like this, which works as of 1.8.9:

/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {Block:"minecraft:dispenser",Time:1,Data:5}

As you can see the only thing I added was the **Data** tag and then the direction I wanted. The full list of directions and their values is in the link above, but just to reiterate them:

- 0: Dispenser facing down
- 1: Dispenser facing up
- 2: Dispenser facing north
- 3: Dispenser facing south
- 4: Dispenser facing west
- 5: Dispenser facing east

Comment: Also, do you know how to add arrows or something to it?

Comment: /summon FallingSand ~ ~5 ~ {Block:"minecraft:dispenser",Time:1,Data:5,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:262, Slot:0,Count:64}]}} Slot is the position starting from the top left and count is the amount

Comment: Sorry, I'm on mobile and it won't let me edit my old comment, but the command you want is:/summon FallingSand ~ ~ ~ {Block:"minecraft:dispenser",Time:1,Data:5,TileEntityData:{Items:[{id:262, Slot:0,Count:64}]}}  Also, change Id if you don't want arrows rather something else. The old command I was using to test in a command block since the full command is too long as a regular chat command